# Is it possible to make computer Historical record More detail in GLPI

Tags: php

I met some problems when using GLPI, searched on google but get no answer:

In my compony , we want to record the life cycle of the server and the hardware (for example : record Hard disk, memory changes on the server; record  life cycle of a Hard Disk ), so I want to record the changes of server and hardware.

Problem is :

1. Currently the Computer Historical record only model of components, for example when I add a Hard Disk, the Historical shows :*Add a component: SSD - 960G (9)*
   what I want is to record the Hard Disk Serial number (eg. XXXXXX ) in Historical, for example : *Add a component: SSD - 960G (9) - XXXXXX*
   which file should I modify to make Historical to record Hard Disk Serial number , thanks.
2. the second question is also a problem about Historical: in **Component --> "Item - Hard drive link"** , historical record nothing,
   I want to record associate and dissociate computer operation in **"Item - Hard drive link"**'s Historical, in my mind the  format should be :*2018-11-1 9:01  associate - Computer Serial number*
   Can anyone help on it, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution:
I use "Device" as Component: so that both computer and device could record the history.
And I search the device by its ID record in the computer's history.